# Next.js Rewrite causing `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, next.js

I'm using Next.js `middleware` to rewrite my `/_site/[siteUrl]` pages to `[siteUrl].domain.com`

When opening site pages It works locally but on production I'm getting the error `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` (on chrome but different on different browsers).

Full message:

"
This site can’t provide a secure connection

a.****.vercel.app sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
"

Here is my code:

```js
export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const url = req.nextUrl;

  // Get hostname of request (e.g. demo.vercel.pub, demo.localhost:3000)
  const hostname = req.headers.get('host') ?? ``;

  // Get the pathname of the request (e.g. /, /about, /blog/first-post)
  const path = url.pathname;

  /*  You have to replace ".vercel.pub" with your own domain if you deploy this example under your domain.
      You can also use wildcard subdomains on .vercel.app links that are associated with your Vercel team slug
      in this case, our team slug is "platformize", thus *.platformize.vercel.app works. Do note that you'll
      still need to add "*.platformize.vercel.app" as a wildcard domain on your Vercel dashboard. */

  const currentHost =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && process.env.VERCEL === '1'
      ? hostname
          .replace(`.vercel.pub`, '')
          .replace(`.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN}`, '')
      : hostname.replace(`.localhost:3000`, '');

  // rewrite root application to `/home` folder
  if (
    hostname === 'localhost:3000' ||
    hostname === process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN
  ) {
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(`${path}`, req.url));
  }

  // rewrite everything else to `/_sites/[site] dynamic route
  return NextResponse.rewrite(
    new URL(`/_sites/${currentHost}${path}`, req.url)
  );
}
```

It works correctly for app pages.

Reference: https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-multi-tenant-application